# How change dimension programmatically?

Tags: android, dimension

I have more dimens

```
<resources>
    <dimen name="tag_text_size">10dp</dimen>
    <dimen name="text_separator_size">15dp</dimen>
    <dimen name="tag_text_count_size">8dp</dimen>
    <dimen name="text_home_page_size">20dp</dimen>
    <dimen name="item_text_head_size">15dp</dimen>
    <dimen name="item_text_time_size">10dp</dimen>
    <dimen name="item_text_price_size">14dp</dimen>
    <dimen name="item_text_address_pattern_size">12dp</dimen>
    <dimen name="item_text_address_size">14dp</dimen>
 <dimen name="setting_text_head_size">24dp</dimen>
  <dimen name="order_text_comment_size">11dp</dimen>
</resources>
```

and i use this dimen in my XML ..

```
 <TextView
 android:textSize="@dimen/item_text_head_size" />
```

...

**I want to programmatically change the dimen, it will allow me to change the size of strings everywhere**

how can this be solved?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It is impossible to set the values for the `dimen` variables in your `dimen.xml` file programmatically from the activity.

The way to do what you want is to delete your `android:textSize` attributes and to change the text size at runtime using `setTextSize()` in Java.

Comment: Oh, I see what he is trying to do. I thought he meant reuse his values from his xml programmitically, not edit the file. sorry. +1